# Node.js app running on heroku - can't find module ./http

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. I have a node.js app using Express and MongoDB (mongoose). It runs perfectly fine locally. I deployed it to heroku seemingly without a problem, but when I try to actually launch the app it crashes. The heroku log says this:

```
macbook-pro-4:FF_Courtney cmitchell$ heroku logs
2012-10-29T19:31:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-10-29T19:31:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web.js`
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './http'
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename     (module.js:338:15)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:378:17)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous>  (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:13:18)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2012-10-29T19:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
2012-10-29T19:31:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I have a package.json file with my dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "favorite-failure",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.6",
    "ejs" : "latest",
    "mongoose" : "3.3.1",
    "request" : "2.11.4",
    "moment" : "1.7.2",
    "mongodb" : "0.9.6-7",
    "connect-mongodb": ">= 1.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
      "node": ">= 0.8.12",
      "npm": ">= 1.1.49"
  }
}
```

I'm a bit new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!